# "Module exports cannot be changed externally" on SP classic page

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Created webpart and verified that it works fine on local workbench. Added webpart to SharePoint and it worked fine until suddenly one day it broke.

[SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:
Unable to load web part WebPart.MyWebPart.g_daeb805f_ec7c_416c_a3e4_1a4455ebd9bb,Error: ***Failed to load component "5b2f272b-f297-4349-9bb8-5de280e0810e" (MyWebPart).
Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "5b2f272b-f297-4349-9bb8-5de280e0810e" (MyWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/5b2f272b-f297-4349-9bb8-5de280e0810e_0.0.1
    **Module exports cannot be changed externally**. script resources due to: {1}.

***CALLSTACK:
Error
    at t [as constructor] (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-04-07.009/classic-pages-assembly_en-us_8fb13c5ec4cb2abb742c685f2ddbe6c6.js:109:25521...

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the SharePoint Framework have you used to build your web part? Could it be that it's an older version than the GA version which is used in SharePoint Online?

Comment: It is GA version. Any ideas how to start debugging / solving these kind of issues?

Comment: Could it be that someone updated the web part manifest without updating the code which is why they are out of sync? Can you reproduce the issue with a new web part?

Comment: Puuh, got it finally working!

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components

"Important: You must upgrade existing projects to use @microsoft/sp-build-web@1.0.1 or later to use Office UI Fabric React. See instructions at the end of this article."

So I needed to update @microsoft/sp-build-web package to get Office UI Fabric React components working.